# Server works over IP with port but not domain and port

Tags: nginx, debian, cloudflare

I have plugged CloudFlare to my server and redirected domain to its' nameservers.

The default domain sends the typical "Server Down" website from CloudFlare - which is fine, because I have nothing under ports 80 and 443 - but "domain.com:3000" instead returns connection timed out.

However, when I call ":3000" it works all dandy.

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
upstream web {
    server web:3000;
}

server {
    listen 3000 ssl;
    http2 on;
    server_name the_ip_here the_domain_here;

    # SSL configuration
    include /data/snippets/ssl-setup.conf;

    # Logging
    access_log /data/logs/web.access.log;
    error_log /data/logs/web.error.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 900;
        proxy_pass http://web$request_uri;
    }
}
```

The service is dockerized, hence the upstream - but it shouldn't matter because it works over IP.

No firewall running, and still shouldn't be blocking only CloudFlare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default domain sends the typical "Server Down" website from CloudFlare - which is fine, because I have nothing under ports 80 and 443 - but "domain.com:3000" instead returns connection timed out.

Cloudflare is a reverse proxy for you. They provide a HTTP/HTTPS proxy. They do not proxy random ports. If you need that, you should look into [Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/application-services/products/cloudflare-spectrum/).

Why not simply move your service to port 80 or 443?

Comment: That's a fair point. The issue was, there were two web apps - both consuming single API, and there wasn't a lot of manouvers for code changes.

Comment: There are different ways to "combine" several services. One aproach is to use a local installed reverse proxy, nginx can do this as well, and "remap" the services to different URL, like so: `web:3000 -> web:80/app1`, `web:3001 -> web:80/app2` or you use a another subdomain or another IP address to host (or a combination of both).

Comment: Of course, that's what I have. The issue was, I couldn't change paths inside apps, and they cross-communicate.